# Is the M1 chip on the 2021 24" iMac the same as the M1 chip on the 2020 Macbook Air?

Tags: performance, apple-silicon

My workplace is offering me a choice of either a 24" iMac (2021) with 8GB RAM and 256GB SSD, or a Macbook Air (2020) with twice as much RAM and storage.  Both have, as far as I can tell, the same M1 chip.

Obviously the most notable difference between these two devices is the size and form factor: the 24" iMac display has almost 3.5x as much real estate as the 13" Macbook Air does. But what I'm wondering about is the performance and speed of the two devices.  Is it really the same M1 chip in both?  Should I expect one of these devices to run faster, more reliably, etc. than the other?

Since people have asked in the comments:  I am a Lecturer at a University.  The most intensive thing I use it for is teaching on Zoom while keeping six Google Jamboards simultaneously open in different windows, while Google Drive syncs in the background. But my current computer (a 2013 iMac) has become so slow that I cannot simultaneously run Zoom, Google Drive, and Firefox without one or more of them crashing.

But just to be clear:  I am **not asking** for advice or opinions on which system to buy, or whether a laptop or desktop is better for my use case.  I can decide that for myself!  I am just wondering whether I can expect one of these two systems to run (generally) faster than the other, given that they have the same CPU but one has twice as much RAM. My naive instinct is to usually assume that a newer desktop computer would have some kind of performance advantage over a (slightly) older Macbook. Is there any reason to think that is the case here?

Comment: Screen real estate is always a boon, but your use case needs evaluating. Do you need portability? Are you doing high-end graphics/video/audio?

Comment: Without insights into the actual work you do with your Mac this will end up with collecting opinions instead of answers.

Comment: While the suitability might be "opinion-based," it seems to me that the actual stated question is not.

Comment: @WGroleau The title asks about M1s (which are the same), the content about performance differences between M1 with 8 vs 16 GB of RAM (which exists but it depends on the workload). Honestly, with the activities described, I would go for the 16 GB machine and buy an external monitor.

Comment: I feel the same, but if you want to interpret the question as _only_ the title, then it is still not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I am just wondering whether I can expect one of these two systems to
> run (generally) faster than the other, given that they have the same
> CPU but one has twice as much RAM."

Yes, they both have the same M1 CPU. However, there are limiting factors on the M1's performance in both options. There is no fan cooling in the MBA, so it will throttle performance to reduce heat, if necessary.

Conversely, the limited RAM in the iMac may also be a performance bottleneck; though these Macs do have impressive resilience when swapping out to disk, because of the fast SSD.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same chip see apple documents for that e.g. [imac](https://www.apple.com/uk/imac-24/specs/)

Make sure you get 16G memory in either case. Not getting that is really a problem. Not so much necessarily on performance but on how much your company values your time, the extra cost is minimal

However the important difference is do you want a laptop or a desktop ie do you want to use it in more than one place.

Comment: 16G memory is only an option if I choose the MacBook.

Comment: @mweiss That's a limit set by your workplace, Apple offers M1 iMacs with 16 GB RAM as well.

Comment: I mean, I know that? I’m asking about the options I *have*, not the ones I don’t.

Comment: @mweiss Saw that only after posting the comment. So yes, it's the same CPU, but the SoC is different (which, depending on the things you'll do with your Mac) will have a more or less significant impact on performance.

Comment: @mweiss We can't take the decision for you :-)

Comment: I didn’t ask you to. Just wanted to know what kind of performance I can expect with each option.

Comment: I would go back to your firm - the extra memory is £200 after VAT - so that is a small extra to buy You mill make that back within weeks

Comment: @mweiss You need to exactly say what your workload will be as the difference is complex

Comment: I fond even the 16GB M1s are a bit sticky with paging. I wouldn't touch an 8GB based on that.

Comment: @Tetsujin I totally agree - and that is just really a web browser - using VMs for Docker etc would be bad